# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'order clause' yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am trying to query the database using `CDbCriteria` in `Yii 1`. What I am doing is:

```
$criteria->addInCondition('t.id', $dealIdArr);
$criteria->order = "FIELD(t.id, $dealIdArr)";
```

And this is the `$dealIdArr` and it's not empty:

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 2 )
```

But when run the script, it returns the error:

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]:
>   Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'order clause'.

I'm unable to understand what is wrong with this? Any help?

Comment: I don't know what are you triyng to do but string representation of array is word `Array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently adding an array to both conditions. I'm not too familiar with Yii, but I'm quite sure that it expects a string for the order - and not an array.

You can `implode()` it to convert it to a string.

```
$dealIdStr = implode(", ", $dealIdArr);
$criteria->addInCondition('t.id', $dealIdArr); // You can use array here
$criteria->order = "FIELD(t.id, $dealIdStr)"; // This expects a string
```

As your array currently only contains integers (3 and 2), you don't need to quote that - but if the array for any reason contains strings, you need to have them quoted in MySQL by doing

```
$dealIdStr = implode("', '", $dealIdArr);
$criteria->order = "FIELD(t.id, '$dealIdStr')";
```

Notice the added single-quotes.

When you try to use an array as a string, PHP will simply print "Array", which is what you're seeing now. And since its not quoted, MySQL think its a column, and not a string.

- http://php.net/implode

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer, Got it. Had to pass the string instead of array. My bad!